# jvisualvm thread cpu time usage

Tags: java, performance, jvisualvm

I'm using the **`jvisualvm`** to monitor the running java program. when I dig into the details of thread cpu usage, I get the following picture. The CPU usage consists of file portions: Running, Sleeping, Wait, Park and Monitor.

I didn't find any official definition about the columns, so I'd like to know what are these columns really mean in java code.

- `Running`: time used in executing.
- `Sleeping`: Thread.sleep(long) ?
- `Wait`: ?
- `Park`: LockSupport.park ?
- `Monitor`: ?

[image: Thread CPU time usage]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a simple test and found these columns can map to the java code operations:

- **Sleeping**: `Thread.sleep(..)`
- **Wait**: `Object.wait(..)`
- **Park**: when you're using new concurrent objects introduce in jdk5+, which may used `LockSupport.park`.
- **Monitor**: when invoke `synchronized` method/objects

So, wait/park/monitor all means the thread is `blocked`, but blocked by different reasons.

---

If a thread is waiting on a socket, the time may be counted on `Running`.

[image]

In this picture, **Thread-pool-Bill** is `Running` for most of time, but the truth is it is waiting on a socket for a very long time:

```
"Thread-pool-Bill" - Thread t@42
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    - locked <79f0aad8> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Running: Time the thread is running on CPU
- Sleeping: Time the thread slept due to `Thread.sleep(…)`
- Wait: Time the thread waited on a resource (e.g. socket/tty)
- Park: Time the thread was parked due to LockSupport.park()
- Monitor: Time the thread was blocked on a monitor (as Evans Y. correctly pointed out, monitors are invoked on `synchronized` blocks/functions)

Comment: so what does a `monitor` mean?